# AWS IAM Inline policy for Password Expiration

Tags: amazon-iam

I have a AWS account and different departments like Accounts, Developers and QA. I want to have a different password expiration policy for each departments. I tried with customs policy and its applicable for the users in account. Is it possible to change the password expiry groupwise?

Thanks in Advance.

I tried changing the Default to custom password policy but it is applying for all the users in the account.